# Is there an equation that can automatically tune a PID controller?

Tags: dynamics, mathematics, pid-control, robotics, kinematics

Is there an equation that can automatically tune PID controllers? or do I have to do manually/make an AI to do it for me?

Comment: Please describe the system being controlled also. For open loop stable systems, a few techniques exist.

Comment: There seems to be a small list of (auto) tuning methods at [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller). But they may be applicable only for systems with simple behaviour.

Comment: If tuning without knowing system characteristics it would be an algorithm, not an equation (where you would actually be modelling the system). Yes they exist, and they work kind of. At least for simple systems where you only need moderate performance. And some are proprietary so it is not a set in stone kind of thing. You are probably better tuning manually at least once even if it takes you a while so you can at least learn what gotchas might arise before using auto-tune.

Comment: there are many auto tuning methods.  the one you use depends on the response you want- for example sometimes overshoot is unacceptable.  You will need the model of the plant you wish to control- usually when figuring out that model, you can come up with what constraints you need on the response too.